# Javascript oninput: How to prevent firing on blur (mobile)?

Tags: javascript, mobile, input

I've run into a frustrating problem. The `input` and `change` events have different uses:

- `input` should fire every time an element's value changes
- `change` should fire when an element loses focus, if the value changed

That is the behaviour I'm seeing, **except** when I test on mobile (Android Chrome). On mobile, the `input` event is firing for both scenarios: every time there's a change, **and** when it loses focus.

[Here's a JSFiddle to test](https://jsfiddle.net/L3m2gkxm/), and an example:

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<script>
    // On mobile, this will fire an extra time when the input loses focus!
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', console.log);
</script>
```

This is conflicting with my desired behaviour for a component, and I'm not having much luck getting rid of it. It is being fired *before* the `blur` and `change` events, so I haven't been able to prevent it there, and I haven't found anything in the event itself that discriminates it from a regular `input` event. Anyone have ideas?

I'm testing on Android Chrome 56.0.2924.87, I'd definitely appreciate feedback if there is similar behaviour on other mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll probably have to do is store the `lastValue` in an array, and then check the current value against `lastValue`, and only do things if there is a difference.

```
let lastValue = null;
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (this.value === lastValue) {
        return; // do nothing
    }

    lastValue = this.value;
    // do something
});
```